# Why do I sometimes get a 404 error when I call msa api using the webclient?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webclient

There are some springboot containers in the ECS.
A container is calling api from other containers such as B, C, etc. to the webclient.

Obviously, other containers are working, but very occasionally, the following error occurs when you call the webclient.

The server was operating at that time, and there are even logs that responded to requests from other APIs.

```html
2023-11-14T01:51:44.292015743Z org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$NotFound: 404 Not Found from GET http://localhost:30440/api/test
2023-11-14T01:51:44.292024957Z  at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException.create(WebClientResponseException.java:202)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.292026787Z  at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultClientResponse.lambda$createException$1(DefaultClientResponse.java:207)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.292027577Z  at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:106)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.292028705Z  at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.292362211Z  at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:101)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.292366728Z  at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:539)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.292457989Z  at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.292459774Z  at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWrite.java:107)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294668583Z  at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:299)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294674773Z  at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:337)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294676666Z  at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294678113Z  at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollect.java:160)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294679570Z  at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294681031Z  at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:260)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294682335Z  at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294683970Z  at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundComplete(FluxReceive.java:400)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294685188Z  at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundComplete(ChannelOperations.java:419)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294687234Z  at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.terminate(ChannelOperations.java:473)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294688651Z  at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:703)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294689770Z  at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:93)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294691070Z  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294692194Z  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294693408Z  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294694820Z  at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294695991Z  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294697894Z  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294699430Z  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294700728Z  at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294701977Z  at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:327)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294702985Z  at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:299)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294705841Z  at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294706960Z  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294708135Z  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294709131Z  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294710383Z  at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294711755Z  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294713163Z  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294714287Z  at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294715772Z  at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:800)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294717040Z  at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:487)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294718575Z  at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:385)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294722099Z  at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294723954Z  at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294725738Z  at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294727421Z  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294728672Z  Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294730471Z      at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:99)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294731903Z      at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1707)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294733326Z      at gopos.msa.service.GoposPosService.getTouchkey(GoposPosService.java:354)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294735069Z      at gopos.master.MasterController.getTouchkey(MasterController.java:501)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294736666Z      at gopos.master.MasterController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$50bfea48.invoke(<generated>)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294737978Z      at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294740150Z      at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294741642Z      at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294743418Z      at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294745058Z      at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:57)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294746448Z      at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294748118Z      at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294750260Z      at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:89)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294751662Z      at cmm.aop.RequestAop.loggingRequestInfo(RequestAop.java:83)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294753323Z      at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor68.invoke(Unknown Source)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294754447Z      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294755654Z      at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294757194Z      at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:634)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294758763Z      at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:624)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294760120Z      at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:72)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294761633Z      at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294763142Z      at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294764728Z      at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294766168Z      at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294767971Z      at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294769679Z      at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294771261Z      at gopos.master.MasterController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$674b05c3.getTouchkey(<generated>)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294773017Z      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294774709Z      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294776420Z      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294777911Z      at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294778941Z      at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294780152Z      at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294781667Z      at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294783067Z      at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294784524Z      at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294785892Z      at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294787044Z      at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1070)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294788309Z      at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294789680Z      at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294790954Z      at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294792114Z      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294918957Z      at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294922308Z      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294923246Z      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294924149Z      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294925239Z      at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294926114Z      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294926744Z      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294927670Z      at cmmcloud.filter.SqlInjectionFilter.doFilter(SqlInjectionFilter.java:25)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294928573Z      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294929326Z      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294930341Z      at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294931015Z      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.294931713Z      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.295796759Z      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.295800832Z      at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.296276211Z      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.296280307Z      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.296334691Z      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.296335735Z      at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.296591053Z      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.296594278Z      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.296595461Z      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.296596452Z      at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.296597176Z      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.296597973Z      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.296598999Z      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.296600422Z      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.296660572Z      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.296663422Z      at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.296664360Z      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.296665646Z      at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.296666557Z      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.296667487Z      at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.296668851Z      at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.296670293Z      at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.296671118Z      at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.296928968Z      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.296931920Z      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.296932714Z      at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.296933290Z      at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.296933911Z      at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
2023-11-14T01:51:44.296935126Z      ... 1 more
```

What is the problem?